# PostGIS - restrict result to the viewport of the map

Tags: php, openlayers, kml, postgis

I have imported few shp files into PostGIS/PostgreSQL DB. Now I want to display the same on the OSM map using OpenLayers. As there are millions of records for the selected county, I want to only fetch those geometries that are within the viewport of the map in the browser.

Also, how should I fetch this data into the map? Is KML a good option? I am using PHP at the backendn and would like to know if I can use it instead of installing a geo server.

I have tried to find an example on the net but couldn't find any. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [BBOX Strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) for getting stuff within a bounding box. Then look at [Vector layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html) for getting them on the map. I don't have an example right now, but if I find one I will complete my answer.

You can use PHP to process the answers if you want to keep it simple. Just use a PHP page as datasource for the layer, and with the BBOX strategy you will always get info on the bounding box and the PHP page can get the correct features.